# Selecting sample rows from queried list of tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On the newbie struggle bus and using Snowflake. I queried to find all of the tables in a database that have a column name containing a certain phrase. Is there a simple-ish way to select 10 (or any number, just something) rows from each of these tables in a single query?

What I’m working with so far:

```
Use database ‘mydatabase’;
     
Select table_name, column_name    
From informationschema.columns   
Where column_name like ‘%phrase%’
```

Let’s say I get 15 tables in the result. I’d like to see a small sample of records from each of those tables so I can confirm what actual values are in those ‘%phrase%’ columns. I’d LOVE to do it without individually querying each table in the list.

Any suggestions for someone who has given up on Googling how to do it?

Comment: Snowflake Scripting is the method to "double" query in one. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

Comment: do you want to see a small sample of each table (`select *`) or of each of those columns?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Thank you for answering and formatting. I will check out Snowflake Scripting!

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Select * from all of the tables

Answer (score 0):

This will take some steps.

First lets construct a query that will sample 10 rows from a list of tables:

```sql
with list_cols as (
    select table_name, column_name    
    from information_schema.columns   
    where column_name like '%WEEK%'
), tables as (
    select distinct table_name
    from list_cols
)

select 'select * from ' || listagg(x, ' union all \n')
from (
    select '(select \''|| table_name || '\' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from ' || table_name || ' x limit 10)' x
    from tables
)
```

The above query will return a value like:

```sql
select * from (select 'CLAIRE_DECAYING' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from CLAIRE_DECAYING x limit 10) union all 
(select 'CLAIRE_DECAYING_HUGE' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from CLAIRE_DECAYING_HUGE x limit 10) union all 
(select 'DECAY_PUZZLE' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from DECAY_PUZZLE x limit 10) union all 
(select 'DECAY_PUZZLE_100M' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from DECAY_PUZZLE_100M x limit 10) union all 
(select 'DECAY_PUZZLE_10M' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from DECAY_PUZZLE_10M x limit 10) union all 
(select 'QL2_CARS_WEEKLY_VIZ' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from QL2_CARS_WEEKLY_VIZ x limit 10) union all 
(select 'SAMPLE_TABLE' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from SAMPLE_TABLE x limit 10) union all 
(select 'QL2_CARS_WEEKLY' table_name, object_construct(x.*) sample_row from QL2_CARS_WEEKLY x limit 10)
```

Which is a query that you can run to get 10 sample rows of each input able.

Note that we use `object_construct(*)` to get around the need for each `select` to have the same # of columns: The whole row gets represented in one column.

Then to have that query run and get its output, you can either copy paste it and run it, or capture that value and `execute immediately`:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html

[image]